# How to run two servers in single solution in NodeJS in VSCode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, socket.io, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using a bot application and a dynamic web page in Node-js which requires to use restify, http, express servers. I am able to use only one of them at a time. But I need to use them simultaneously which will listen to single port. I am unable to configure the application as such. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you run with different ports

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement that, you have to declare restify, http, express in a single server.

```
var server = restify.createServer();
server= require("express")();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
});
```